# Charge someone with something (figurative usage)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, difference

According to the [dictionary definition](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/charge), "charging someone with something" means to make a formal statement saying that someone is accused of a crime:

> She's been charged with murder.

But I wonder what verb can be used in not legislative atmosphere, but in normal everyday speech when one is say **charging** the other one with e.g. lying.

Example:

> What the hell are you talking about Sandy? Are you charging me with lying?

Does the verb 'charge' work here figuratively or there is another verb for this case.

Aside from "charge" the only close word with the same part of speech that comes to my mind is "accuse someone of something", but as you know well, that is not at all the same as 'charge' semantically.

Please kindly explain that to me.

Comment: No, it also means ‘be given a job or responsibility’. Diana has been charged with looking after her 2 nieces. Means, she has been given responsibility to babysit. Further a slightly old fashioned usage calls the nieces ‘her charges’ - kids she is responsible for. Another example: Charged with redeveloping the Asia division, Mr. Tibbs has newly redecorated all client areas.

Comment: I think you know all there is to know about it.  Note Jelila's addition.  The next most common thing is just "saying", in which case you often have constructions like "are you saying I'm lying?" or equivalently "are you saying I'm a liar?"  Definitely only use charging for some kind of administrative context.

Comment: I think "Are you accusing me of lying?" would be much more natural.